# Install OpenSSL-style SSL certificate on Windows

Tags: putty, ssl, certificate, filezilla

Context: I am writing an application that needs to connect to an FTP server, which may be FTPS (i.e. it might be encrypted with TLS.) To test it, I have installed FileZilla Server and (with it) generated a certificate file (which looks exactly like a putty-generated key: base64 split into 65-character lines,) however I can't find a way to import this certificate into Windows Certification Authority.

How do I do this?

Certificate file looks something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which looks exactly like a putty-generated key: base64 split into 65-character lines

But that's where the similarities end. This just happens to be a particularly common ASCII-armoring format, originally from the PEM e-mail security format (hence the .pem file extension that you often see on such things). It's not a "PuTTY-style" key; a better name would be "OpenSSL-style key".

(PuTTY is an SSH client; it doesn't even use SSL/TLS and it does not support X.509 ("SSL") certificates. The only thing they have in common is private keys – it so happens that OpenSSH uses the same RSA key format (PKCS#1) as OpenSSL does, so that's what you get from PuTTYgen's "Export OpenSSH key" too. In fact, PuTTY's *own* ".ppk" format looks quite different.)

So what you have is a PEM-encoded X.509 certificate and a PEM-encoded PKCS#1 RSA private key. If you want to import *just* the certificate, you can put it in a file on its own and name it `something.crt` or `something.cer` – Windows will recognize the PEM-encoding automatically.

But if you want to import the certificate *with private key* into Windows, the only thing it'll accept is PKCS#12 format (files with the .p12 or .pfx extension). To convert between the two formats, you can use the `openssl` program:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in FTP.pem -inkey FTP.pem -out FTP.p12 -name "FileZilla cert"
```

(The PKCS#12 file will be password-encrypted. Avoid non-ASCII letters in the password. OpenSSL for Windows [can be found here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).)

Before doing so, I strongly recommend generating a *new* keypair, and not using the one that you just pasted for the whole Internet to see.